# win32 api reading combo box value from a dialog box with two combo boxes

Tags: c++, api, winapi, combobox

I have two combobox in one dialogbox, the thing is that I want to find out which string has been selected and get the message from the combobox. I have the following code. but the problem is that from this code I can not distinguish which one of the comboboxes has been selected and this code results in having the same index number for both boxes.

```
if(HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELCHANGE){
        _formatIndex = SendMessage((HWND) lParam, (UINT) CB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) IDD_IMAGES_MODE);
        _savingModeIndex = SendMessage((HWND) lParam, (UINT) CB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) IDC_COMBOBOX_TIME_FRAME);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I just find the answer, here is the code :

```
    if(HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_SELCHANGE){
        if(LOWORD(wParam)==IDD_IMAGES_MODE){
        _formatIndex = SendMessage((HWND) lParam, (UINT) CB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) 0);
        }
        if(LOWORD(wParam)==IDC_COMBOBOX_TIME_FRAME){
        _savingModeIndex = SendMessage((HWND) lParam, (UINT) CB_GETCURSEL, (WPARAM) 0, (LPARAM) 0);
        }           
    }
```